# Could lambda return throttling error even if it doesn't reach maximum concurrency number(1000)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Here is the situation I suffer.

1. `Lambda` has 1000 concurrency limit. (There is no reserved number)
2. 100-200 Clients access to `Lambda` at a time.
3. `Lambda` still doesn't reach throttling in the figures(100-200).
4. However, `Lambda` returns a lot of `502` errors.

And I assume

1. The first time, any `Lambda` isn't up.
2. When `Lambda` receives a lot of requests, it starts scaling.
3. However, because of `Lambda`'s `cold start time`, It takes time to execute enough concurrency to handle all requests and as the result, it returns the error(even if it is not reached to maximum concurrency execution number[1000])

Is my assumption correct? If so, is it inevitable situation?

I have read on warming `Lambda` by sending ping requests at regular interval to the `Lambda`.
However, It looks not to solve the above issue because the ping is sent to only one `Lambda` making only the `Lambda` is resued, causing the same issue when a lot of requests is received at a time.

------Edit------

About `@M Mo`'s asking

1. How are the lambdas being invoked?

   - By `API-getaway` it is invoked.
2. If through api gateway, are you using proxy integration?

   - Yes, `proxy integration`.
3. Do the lambdas call any other resources?

   - Yes, The `Lambda` calls `S3` resource to get objects.
4. What are the average response times of the lambdas?

   - it takes about 1 sec.

Comment: If you are trying to invoke these functions synchronously with that much burst, you are probably going to have problems. Asynchronous executions should back up and eventually run even if it takes a bit to spin up all the containers. You could try to switch to async invokes, or stagger the clients more. Another thing to note, is even though Lambda has a high concurrency limit, if it is inside your VPC you are limited to the number of ENI's that can be spun up concurrently, which by default is 350 per region, but could be even less depending on your subnets.

Comment: How are the lambdas being invoked? If through api gateway, are you using proxy integration? Do the lambdas call any other resources? What are the average response times of the lambdas?

Comment: @K Mo, I edit the post by your asking. please check it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you able to attach an image of the CloudWatch metrics showing ConcurrentExecutions and Throttles?